# MongoDB query to find text in third level array of objects

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a Mongo collection that contains data on saved searches in a Vue/Laravel app, and it contains records like the following:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("6202f3357a02e8740039f343"), 
    "q" : null, 
    "name" : "FCA last 3 years", 
    "frequency" : "Daily", 
    "scope" : "FederalContractAwardModel", 
    "filters" : {
        "condition" : "AND", 
        "rules" : [
            {
                "id" : "awardDate", 
                "operator" : "between_relative_backward", 
                "value" : [
                    "now-3.5y/d", 
                    "now/d"
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "id" : "subtypes.extentCompeted", 
                "operator" : "in", 
                "value" : [
                    "Full and Open Competition"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
```

The problem is the `value` in the item in the `rules` array that has the decimal.

```
"value" : [
    "now-3.5y/d", 
    "now/d"
]
```

in particular the decimal. Because of a UI error, the user was allowed to enter a decimal value, and so this needs to be fixed to remove the decimal like so.

```
"value" : [
    "now-3y/d", 
    "now/d"
]
```

My problem is writing a Mongo query to identify these records (I'm a Mongo noob). What I need is to identify records in this collection that have an item in the `filters.rules` array with an item in the 'value` array that contains a decimal.

Piece of cake, right?

Here's as far as I've gotten.

```
myCollection.find({"filters.rules": })
```

but I'm not sure where to go from here.

**UPDATE:** After running the regex provided by @R2D2, I found that it also brings up records with a valid date string , e.g.

```
        "rules" : [
            {
                "id" : "dueDate", 
                "operator" : "between", 
                "value" : [
                    "2018-09-10T19:04:00.000Z", 
                    null
                ]
            },
```

so what I need to do is filter out cases where the period has a double 0 on either side (i.e. `00.00`). If I read the regex correctly, this part

```
[^\.]
```

is excluding characters, so I would want something like

```
[^00\.00]
```

but running this query

```
db.collection.find( {
         "filters.rules.value": { $regex:  /\.[^00\.00]*/ } 
         } )
```

still returns the same records, even though it works as expected in a regex tester. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find all documents containing at least one value string  with (.) , try:

```
    db.collection.find( {
         "filters.rules.value": { $regex:  /\.[^\.]*/ } 
         } )
```

Or you can filter only the fields that need fix via aggregation as follow:

```
 [direct: mongos]> db.tes.aggregate([ {$unwind:"$filters.rules"}, {$unwind:"$filters.rules.value"}, {$match:{ "filters.rules.value": {$regex:  /\.[^\.]*/    } }}  ,{$project:{_id:1,oldValue:"$filters.rules.value"}}       ])
[
 { _id: ObjectId("6202f3357a02e8740039f343"), oldValue: 'now-3.5y/d' }
]
[direct: mongos]>
```

Later to update those values:

```
 db.collection.update({
   "filters.rules.value": "now-3.5y/d"
   },
   {
     $set: {
      "filters.rules.$[x].value.$": "now-3,5y/d-CORRECTED"
    }
   },
   {
     arrayFilters: [
   {
     "x.value": "now-3.5y/d"
   }
  ]
  })
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/j4IvKbRqBWG)

Comment: Awesome! So when running the first one, I discovered that it also finds records that have a time value (e.g. `"2018-12-03T13:27:00.000Z"`), so I think I just need to tweak the regex to filter out cases where the zero has two zeros on either side (e.g. `00.00`).